# Differences between ipython %run and promt

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I've the following simple erroneous code

```
from numpy import random, sqrt
points = random.randn(20,3);
points = points / sqrt(sum(points**2,1))
```

In ipython (with `%autoreload 2`) if I copy and paste it into the terminal I get a `ValueError` as one would expect. If I save this as a file and use %run then it runs without error (it shouldn't).

What's going on here?

Comment: There's no `ValueError` thrown by this piece of code.

Comment: There is in my ipython shell (because it has numpy loaded by default)... see below.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out, but I had written the question and it might be useful to someone else.

It is a difference between the numpy `sum` and the native `sum`. Changing the first line to

```
from numpy import random, sqrt, sum
```

fixes it as `%run` uses the native version by default (at least with my settings). The native run does not take an axis parameter, but does not throw an error either, because it is a `start` parameter, which is in effect just an offset to the sum. So,

```
>>> sum([1,2,3],10000)
10006
```

for the native version. And "axis out of bounds" for the numpy one.